# What argument types can Spring inject into a Controller handler method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As the title already says, what target types can I use on Spring MVC's @ModelAttribute annotation when applying it to a method argument?

I know about the following syntax (which I myself have used frequently):

```
public void finishForm(@ModelAttribute UserInfo info) {
      .......
      return model;
}
```

This would be part of a form backing controller where Spring Databinding is doing all the parsing and subsequently populates my custom object (`UserInfo`).

But in my current case it would be more convenient to populate a Java `Properties` object or a `Map<String, String>` with the form input.

Would this be a valid use case and can you provide a reference with all target types for @ModelAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to get all your form input in a Map you can use the following:

```
public void finishForm(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, String[]> userInfo = request.getParameterMap();

        userInfo.keySet().forEach(s -> {
            System.out.println(s + " = "+Arrays.toString(userInfo.get(s)));
        });        
    }
```